# Ranking with PHP on certain condition

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, ranking

I have marks scored by several students in php array.

$firstarray:

```
Array ( 
       [0] => Array ( 
             [6] => Array ( //I want to skip this student from ranking
                     [ENGLISH] => 45.00 
                     [MATHEMATICS] => 5.00 
                     [SCIENCE] => 40.00 
                    ) 
                ) 
      [1] => Array ( 
             [7] => Array ( 
                     [ENGLISH] => 41.00 
                     [MATHEMATICS] => 40.00 
                     [SCIENCE] => 47.00 
                     ) 
                ) 
      ) 
      [2] => Array ( 
             [8] => Array ( 
                     [ENGLISH] => 42.00 
                     [MATHEMATICS] => 44.00 
                     [SCIENCE] => 40.00 
                     ) 
                )
      [3] => Array ( 
             [9] => Array ( 
                     [ENGLISH] => 42.00 
                     [MATHEMATICS] => 25.00 
                     [SCIENCE] => 31.00 
                     ) 
                ) 
      )
```

In another array, I have the total mark scored by each student with the ranking.:

$secondarray:

```
Array ( [7] => 
           Array ( 
             [score] => 128 
             [rank] => 1 
            ) 
        [8] => 
           Array ( 
             [score] => 126
             [rank] => 2 
            ) 
        [9] => 
           Array ( 
             [score] => 98
             [rank] => 3 
            ) 
       [6] => 
           Array ( 
             [score] => 90 
             [rank] => 4 
            ) 
        )
```

After taking out the students total mark scored in all subjects, I used the following php code to calculate the ranking with ties:

$totalmarkscore:

```
   Array ( 
       [0] => Array ( 
            [6] => 90 
           ) 
       [1] => Array ( 
            [7] => 128 
           ) 
       [2] => Array ( 
            [8] => 126 
           )
       [3] => Array ( 
            [9] => 98
           ) 
       ) 

   $rankchu =array();
   foreach($totalmarkscore as $k => $vl){
      if(is_array($vl)){
          foreach($vl as $hlutna =>$ken){
             $rankchu[$hlutna]= $ken;
      }
    }
  }
  $secondarray = setRankings($rankchu);
```

My question is: How do I skip calculating the rank of a student who does not get minimum 15 marks from each subject? But I still want to show the student marks scoring detail, I just want to skip it from the ranking and then maintain the ranking order. In the above example, I want to skip the student with id=6 because he did not get minimum 15 mark (he scored only 5 mark) in Mathematics from ranking calculation, other things remaining the same. 
Please help. Thanks.

Comment: How do you know he has only 5 marks? Please show the code, that determines that.

Comment: keep also in mind that if two students are ex aequo, they have the same rank and you need to skip the next one.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte, I did that, I have a ranking function `setRankings($var)` which determines that. Please see my expected output of the $secondarray.

Comment: where do you get your information from? If it is from a database, consider calculation and filtering while queryíng the database

Comment: @IvoP, it is from the database.

Comment: In that case I would recommend to get your data from the database in a format you can use directly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you are processing `$firstarray`, you will need to retain the information whether any of the scores was under 15. Here we add a `can_be_scored` flag to store that:

```
 $totalmarkscore = array_reduce(
   $firstarray,
   function($result, $item) {
     $id = key($item);
     $scores = $item[$id];
     $result[$id] = array(
       "score" => array_sum($scores),
       "can_be_scored" => min($scores) >= 15
     );
     return $result;
   },
   array()
 );
```

With this, `$totalmarkscore` should look something like this:

```
Array (
    [7] => 
       Array ( 
         [score] => 128 
         [can_be_scored] => true
        ) 
    [8] => 
       Array ( 
         [score] => 126
         [can_be_scored] => true
        ) 
    [9] => 
       Array ( 
         [score] => 98
         [can_be_scored] => true
        ) 
   [6] => 
       Array ( 
         [score] => 90 
         [can_be_scored] => false
        ) 
    )
```

Then, in `setRankings`, you can check if `$item["can_be_scored"]` and exclude the item if it is false.

Comment: Solymosi, Please look at my expected output of the $second array.

Comment: It is unclear what exactly you are asking for. You want to include the scores of users with scores less than 15, but exclude them from the ranking calculation? Or do you want to entirely exclude those users from the final array?